# Controlling $null values in variables

Tags: powershell

A question of controlling $null values in variables.

I will try to describe the situation, I load the configuration file

**conf.psd1**

```
@{
    Variables = @{
        Variable1 = 'value1'
    }
}
```

```
$Global:conf = Import-PowerShellDataFile .\conf.psd1
 
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
 
$variable1 = $Global:conf.Variables.Variable1
$variable2 = $Global:conf.Variables.Variable2
 
Write-Debug ("[{0}], [{1}]" -f $variable1, $variable2)
```

> DEBUG: [value1], []

How it is more convenient to control that the config did not have the variable2 key?

```
if (!$variable2){
    thow "variable $variable2 is not defined"
}
```

the only way?

I don't understand why I can access non-existent properties and it doesn't throw an error

```
class foo{}
[foo]::A.B.C
```

Why the "?" if the behavior is the same...

```
class Foo{}
$foo = [Foo]::new()
 
$a = $foo?.A
$b = $foo.B
 
"[$a] [$b]"
```

Comment: You have a typo on `thow`, and that's probably the reason why your script is not working too

Comment: As for acceding properties and not throwing an error, you can use [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Santiago Squarzon, thank you my friend, this is what I have been missing for so long ...

Comment: Some people love it, some people hate it :P

Comment: I'm more of those who love it, it allows you to reduce the debugging time at times